# Search for whole word with Linq to SQL

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm using VB.NET and Linq to SQL to do search query. I'm using the Contains method of Linq to look up the input keyword. It's like this `note.note_content.Contains(InputKeyWord)`.

The problem is that If I search for the "cord" then "according" will also come up. I want the result to be matched with keyword only.

How do I do to search for the whole keyword with Linq ?

Thank you.

Comment: why was this given a -1?  obviously theres answers to this question and something i was glad to find

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that the inputKeyword can appear at the beginning, any place in between and at the end of the note, therefore you need to have 3 OR clauses for the 3 possible places where it can appear. So, your LINQ where clause may end up looking like this.

```
note.note_content.StartsWith(InputKeyword & " ") OR _
note.note_content.EndsWith(" " & InputKeyword) OR _
note.note_content.Contains(" " & InputKeyword & " ")
```

This is not a pretty solution, but It should work. If you are adept with regular expressions, that's an option with LINQ as well.

Read this: [How to Combine LINQ with Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882639.aspx)

Comment: I'm not good at Regex, that's why, I provided the link for you. However, did you try using the where clause in my example?

Comment: I did mark it as the answer but I got the red notice saying "/content/img/vote-accepted.png from the site (click on this box to dismiss)". So, I clicked it several times.

Answer (score 0):

Are the delimiters or spaces around the data? You can use the .Like (InputKeyword) to refine it a bit more.

Comment: I don't think that we have Like method.

Comment: You should have the Like method.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your keywords has delimiters on the beginning and on the end. If that's true, you could use

```
from n in note
where n.note_content.Contains(beginDelimiter + InputKeyWord + endDelimiter) ||
      n.note_content.StartsWith(InputKeyWord + endDelimiter) || 
      n.note_content.EndsWith(beginDelimiter + InputKeyWord)
select n
```

Comment: There's no delimiter. User can search anything like "2 cords", "cord of something".