# full word match query: turning sql into linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, dbcontext

consider a database which contains the following data:

```
id      title
1       cooking assembler
2       time assembler
3       time disassembler
4       time assembly
5       cooking assembly
```

if i type out in sql in the studio manager

```
select id from titles where contains(title, 'assembler')
```

i get 1 and 2 - great 
and if i do this query

```
select id from titles where contains(title, 'disassembler')
```

i get 3 - perf
this is exactly what i want

but now when i jump over to c#
and write this:

```
dbcontext.titles_data.where(t=>t.Contains('assembler')
```

gives me 1,2 AND 3 - not what i want
what is the c# equivalent for the sql i want?

Comment: What does the generated query look like when you debug?

Comment: Check [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/810078/search-for-whole-word-with-linq-to-sql)

Comment: thanks @aliriza - ive adjusted code to reflect the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @aliriza
i applied the solution in this post:
[Search for whole word with Linq to SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/810078/search-for-whole-word-with-linq-to-sql)

the code now looks like:

```
string t = "parrothead";
List<titles> tData = db.titles_data.Where(
    o=> o.title.Contains(" " + t + " ") || 
    o.title.StartsWith(t + " ") || 
    o.title.EndsWith(" "+ t)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
var searchPattern = new Regex(@"\b(assembler)\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var Result = test.Where(i => searchPattern.IsMatch(i));
```

Comment: thank you - but apparently regex does not work with L2E according to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493501/using-match-in-a-linq-statement