# How to use LINQ to Search Word, not just substring?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a array of keywords, kws, and I want to search the database table to see whether it 'include' those keywords in Title column

```
guids = _context.Advertisements.Where(x => kws.Any(kw => x.AdTitle.Contains(kw))).Select(x => x.AdId);
```

The table Advertisements has column AdTitle.

The problem with this is, say I have 'car' in kws, and 'Car123' in table as AdTitle. I do not want to have this one in the returned guids.

I know I can search kw + " " or " " + kw, but what if the car is the first/last word?

Comment: You'd need to use regex for this. Also, you need to define what counts as a word for you because words are not _only_ separated by spaces (think punctuation). I would use `.Contains()` to return potential matches from the database and then use regex to further filter them locally.

Comment: that's what I want to avoid

Comment: Well, unfortunately, you don't have a whole lot of other options. The only other solution I could think of is something like `.Contains(" " + kw + " ") || .StartsWith(kw + " ") || .EndsWith(" " + kw)` but for one, this is very ugly in my opinion, and it falls apart as soon as you have words not separated by a space.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [full word match query: turning sql into linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23947420/full-word-match-query-turning-sql-into-linq)

Comment: what is your table structure, what are `kws` and `kw`? you have just mentioned only one case